# Clean up AngularJs Markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have noticed with `AngularJS` that the `DOM` can get very messy and chaotic. For example:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ngRepeat: st in styles -->
    <li ng-repeat="st in styles" ng-class="{'active': st.id == style.id}" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-click="onStyleChange(st.id)" title="Test Style">
            <span class="image" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/' + st.slug + '.png)'}" style="background-image: url(http://www.bestvinyl.dev/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/alpha-style.png);"></span>
        </a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: st in styles -->
    <li ng-repeat="st in styles" ng-class="{'active': st.id == style.id}" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-click="onStyleChange(st.id)" title="Closed Picket">
            <span class="image" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/' + st.slug + '.png)'}" style="background-image: url(http://www.bestvinyl.dev/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/closed-picket.png);"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This can and has gotten very messy in some of my applications. It makes for debugging the html and css difficult and at time annoying when navigating the `DOM` in the dev tools.

Is there a way to clean up the markup? Possibly removing the `ng-` attributes. I am unsure on all the internals of `AngularJS` so I am not sure what is exactly used or needed after the fact.

This is what I am going for:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ngRepeat: st in styles -->
    <li class="active ng-scope">
        <a title="Test Style">
            <span class="image" style="background-image: url(http://www.bestvinyl.dev/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/alpha-style.png);"></span>
        </a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: st in styles -->
    <li class="ng-scope">
        <a title="Closed Picket">
            <span class="image" style="background-image: url(http://www.bestvinyl.dev/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/closed-picket.png);"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have seen with many similar frameworks that the html is super clean. Reactjs is an example that comes to mind.

Comment: Make directives to separate some of your code and make it cleaner and more understandable

Comment: Well. One way would be to take it all into cotroller and resolve it by function calls. Also all style parts could be done as classes and `ng-class` could be used in most places to lessen the length of markup.

Comment: That's not really the `DOM` and it's neither messy nor chaotic. You also didn't say what you actually want. What would a "clean" version look like? Chrome simply displays the elements and their set attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions in your controller to return your ng-class/ng-style results

i.e.

```
ng-style="getBG(st.slug)"


function getBG(slug){
  var bg = 'url(/sites/local/main/assets/img/styles/' + slug + '.png'

  return {
    'background-image': bg
  }
}
```

Which follows DRY principles